# Jaas and custom hashing algorithm

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jaas

I am trying to use jaas on a jdbcRealm with Glassfish 4. However I have an existing database with existing custom hashed and salted passwords that cannot be directly used by the jaas implementation.

Is there a quick way to override the hashing algorithm of the container with my custom method?

I guess I always have the option of manually updating the database (after I confirm the password with my custom hashing) with the hashed password that the jaas hashing algorithm expects before calling request.login().

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Extend the implementation code of the JdbcRealm and change the parts that do this hashing.

Then register the result as a custom realm.